# Memory allocation - How 15 GB can be equal to 2GB?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

A major application of mine, is crashing at run time.

I want to find out if this is related to a memory allocation issue by the system. Thus, I created a small test program to allocate 1GB of memory and simultaneously ran 15 such processes, thus using 15GB of RAM in total.

However, when I run this program the task manager shows that it has occupied only 2GB of RAM? How is that possible?

I wrote a sample code as follows

```
char *ptr[1024];
for ( i = 0 ; i < 1024 ; ++i )
{
    ptr[i] = new char[1024 * 1024];
    std::cout << " Allocated 1024 MB" << i << " th time " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the OS overcommits? I. e., `new` returns a valid pointer although there's not enough memory. Try *actually* wrting something to the memory obtained, and your process will probably be killed.

Comment: Task manager does not show "occupied amount of memory". It shows [working sets](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-do-the-task-manager-memory-columns-mean) and it's a different thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try storing data in your big arrays.  Memset would do fine.
You are probably looking at actual memory if you don't touch it these could be still only in virtual memroy.

Comment: Thanks Dale. Solved the puzzle by using memset.

Comment: That's a pointless thing to do, it merely slows down a program.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not at all, it faults all those pages and creates physical pages. Otherwise this allocated memory will merely point to a dummy zero page. Since the OP wants to force the system to allocate memory, that's the right thing.

Comment: @Damon - What exactly is the point of "forcing the system to allocate memory?"  What does that test?  Do you think that test is going to fail?

Comment: @HansPassant The point is to experiment and better understand how the OS manages memory.

Comment: @HansPassant: The OP's premise is a "memory allocation issue by the system". I wouldn't know what that is (nor deem it likely on a mainstream OS). Either way, what the OP apparently wants is a VM stress test of sorts. For that you must touch the pages.

Answer (score 13):

Windows is a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  Allocating memory with operator new only allocates *virtual* memory.  You won't start using *physical* memory, RAM, until you actually *access* the memory.  Which you did not do.

You can force the RAM to be allocated by touching every 4096th byte, better make that a write or it will be optimized away:

```
    size_t size = 1024 * 1024;
    ptr[i] = new char[size];
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j += 4096) ptr[i][j] = 0;
```

But that's quite a pointless thing to do, it just slows your program down.  And doesn't actually test anything, a process cannot run out of RAM on Windows.  Put Task Manager into programmer mode, add the column for Commit size.  That's the real number.

Comment: Note that it does ensure that space is available if necessary. Unlike some operating systems, which lie and then have to start killing people to satisfy memory demands.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I would love you have a link to the the technical background.

Comment: @DieterLücking: If it wasn't for a lot of applications doing things like allocating 1MB to read a file into, and if the file is much smaller, not resizing it back down. (Same applies for large static allocations). The OS does this because overall, it is more efficient and more distributed over time than doing a large "populate all the pages". It only really causes problems when all the memory is highly used by lots of different applications - and that's probably meaning that you haven't got enough memory in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the OS overcommits, i. e., `operator new` returns a valid (non-`NULL`) pointer although there's not enough memory. Try *actually writing* something to the memory obtained, and your process will probably be killed (or at least the physical memory usage goes up).

Answer (score 1):

The OS (whether Windows, Linux or MacOS) doesn't expect that all processes that allocate memory to actually USE all that memory. Lots of programs do things like allocate 1MB to hold a file, and then fill it with 14KB of file-data (because it's easier than figuring out how large the file is and actually allocate the right amount). So, instead of going through all the effort of actually making a real physical memory page available for memory that may not be used, it just leaves it allocated in virtual space, and then finds some physical memory when the memory is actually used.

Thus the amount of memory shown in Task Manager is only the actual memory you are using, not the memory you have allocated but never used.

If you write a loop that writes to every 256th or 1024th byte in your allocation, it should "grow" and show your actual amount of allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

You are essentially filling your pagefile with data. The OS sees that you are allocating lots of data, but until you use it, this data won't be pulled from the page file into main memory.